# Resetting a Query using wp_reset_query() or wp_reset_postdata() does not work

Tags: query-posts, wp-reset-postdata, wp-reset-query

I am using ACF as related posts. I have the following code.

```
<?php $post_objects = get_field('repeater_related_items');
if( $post_objects ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $post_objects as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <span><?php the_field('repeater_related_items'); ?></span>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </ul>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>  
<?php endif;?>
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Main Sidebar') ) : endif; ?>
```

The problem is that when I add this to sidebar other widget doesn't work.

Comment: You have reset the post data twice. That could cause trouble in some circumstances, but I suspect the problem is in how you add this to the sidebar. Please edit your question to include that code.

Comment: I just edited my code including sidebar.

Comment: `get_field()` is a custom function of ACF, right? The sidebar is outside of the loop, so how would the function know the post for which to get the specified meta data? Also: please clarify "*other widget doesn't work*": what other Widget, and in what way does it not work?

Comment: Sidebar is not a part of code.

Comment: What kind of data is in the $post_objects variable? An array of ID's?

Answer (score 1):

I removed the following line and fixed.
`<span><?php the_field('repeater_related_items'); ?></span>`

Comment: If possible, can you explain why that might have fixed the issue?